# Intellij IDEA 14 swticher (alt+tab) jumps to one before last file instead of last

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I have following problem. When I hit `alt+tab` once Idea highlight and jump to one before last file instead of last. It's very frustrating. `alt+shift+tab` doesn't work properly as well. It highlights first position in in right column of switcher instead of left. `ctrl+e` and `ctrl+shift+e` work properly.
Did I something wrong or it's Idea's bug?

Answer (score 0):

The top file in the Switcher popup is the file that you currently have open in the editor. Since it doesn't make sense to switch from a file to the same file, the second file is selected by default.

Ctrl-E doesn't include the currently open file in the list, so it selects the first file by default.

Comment: By last I mean last opened file. When I hit alt+tab once switcher opens third file in order instead of second.

Comment: The default Switcher shortcut is Ctrl-Tab. Did you actually remap it to Alt-Tab?

Comment: You right, ctrl+tab :) The problem is very frustrating, when I want to switch fast between last two opened files and it's impossible...

Comment: Do you have any non-default plugins installed? In particular, the TabSwitch plugin, that provided switcher functionality before it became available as a core feature?

Comment: Build number of my Idea's is UI-139.1117 and I think no updates were downloaded since few days